# Tomcat 7 -> Jersey java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/base/Splitter

Tags: java, tomcat, jersey, swagger

I do get the following error when i try to use swagger with jersey in tomcat7:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/base/Splitter
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:489)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:427)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:388)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:341)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:228)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

but i added the jersey-guava-2.24.jar into tomcats lib path through adding that folder (where i put that jar) to catalina.properties at the end of common.loader.

I also know that this folder is working, because otherwise jersey and swagger wouldn't work at all.

Now i'm lost why the class loader can't find it. Anyone an idea how to debug that?

Comment: You added jersey-guava, but you also need to add the core Guava jar. On a side note, adding webapp specific libraries to the common loader can have adverse effects if you ever plan on deploying multiple applications to the same container.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the specific issue was at the end, but i added guava-18 to the tomcat lib after i saw that it was already in my referenced folder. Now it works. I removed the lib from tomcat lib folder and keeping it only in my reference folder and it still works.

I can't remember explicit when i added guava to that folder, i'm irritated but it works now! :)